ERROR tests/test_user_endpoints.py::test_create_user - RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set. with docker
Ok I have tried everything to get pytest working with Docker and I cant seem to get it to fire.
I have a seperate testing container on docker:
    partneraccountstest:
        container_name: partner-accounts-tests
        build: ../partner-accounts-py
        #ports:
        #- "81:6000"
        volumes:
            - ../partner-accounts-py:/app:delegated
        environment:
            - FLASK_ENV=testing
            - FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
            - TEST_DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///:memory
        networks:
            - default
        command: pytest

Then in my app I have a config.py:
class ProductionConfig():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')


class DevelopmentConfig():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DEV_DATABASE_URL')
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    DEBUG = True


class TestConfig():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('TEST_DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///:memory:')
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'default_secret_key')


config_by_name = dict(
    development=DevelopmentConfig,
    production=ProductionConfig,
    testing=TestConfig
)


def get_config(env):
    return config_by_name.get(env, DevelopmentConfig)

So with in my /tests directory i created a conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app():
    app = init_app()

    # Ensure you load the correct config for testing
    app.config.from_object(get_config('testing'))
    print(f"Loaded config: {app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']}")
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        yield app
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

Then finally I have my Test
import pytest
from tests.conftest import client, mock_token


def test_create_user(client, mock_token):
    user = {
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "last_name": "Hope",
        "email": "bob.hope@partneraccount.com",
        "country": "Canada",
        "job_title": "Owner"
    }

    response = client.post('/users/create', json=user)
    json_data = response.get_json()

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert json_data['result']['first_name'] == "Bob"

    from application.models.user import User
    new_user = User.query.filter_by(email='bob.hope@partneraccount.com').first()
    assert new_user is not None
    assert new_user.first_name == 'Bob'

Also for context I use a init.py within a application folder and this is how I build the app
def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    
    app.config.from_object(get_config('development'))
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    migration.init_app(app, db)
    cors.init_app(app)

        with app.app_context():
        from application.blueprints.users import user_blueprint

        app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint)

        return app


I think thats everything and I have tried everything
